# Laravel routes.php include file using Session

Tags: authentication, laravel, routes, laravel-5

Not sure if this is possible, but here it goes.

What I am looking to do is include my "admin" routes as a separate file, only if the user is an admin (therefore a non admin will get a 404 error

### routes.php

```
if( Session::get('user')->is_admin )
    require_once('routes-admin.php');

if( Auth::check() )
    require_once('routes-user.php');

Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('home');
});
```

### routes-admin.php

```
Route::get('admin', function() {
    return view('admin-dashboard');
});
```

### routes-user.php

```
Route::get('user', function() {
    return view('user-dashboard');
});
```

What I am trying to do is avoid having the test repeated with every single `Route`
so if my user segment has 10 pages I currently need 30 lines of code dedicated to `Auth::check()` (the if, else and redirect if not), where I can instead have a single check on `routes.php` and the user will get a `404` if they don't belong

Is there a way to perform this check outside of the `Route`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the response of @Kyslik for the middleware, you can "include" your own routes file in your RouteServiceProvider like the default routes file, the RouteServiceProvide is located in: app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php,

Find the section

```
require app_path('Http/routes.php');
```

and just replicate with the name of your routes file want to include

Comment: Changed accepted answer because this is closer to what I was looking for with my question

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want to read [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-groups) first?

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', function()
    {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });

    Route::get('user/profile', function()
    {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });

});
```

Above code does exactly what you need, is "person logged in?" let him go to page "whatever".

You can create middlewares (check if user is admin or basic user) yourself and apply on groups.

Example [middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware)

```
class BeforeMiddleware implements Middleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Perform action

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

---

Do not get me wrong, just your approach is really not Laravel like. Try to see some open source projects done in L5 or even in L4. Try to use everything Taylor already done for you. Documentation is your firend here.

Comment: Thanks, coming in from 4 I wasn't really thinking about middleware

Comment: No problem, in no way you should ever use `include()` in Laravel app its just bad practise. Please, note that in L4 you have avalible Filters (conceptually same as L5 middlewares).